# Merge [code-efficiency] into [performance]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I'm not sure what the difference between the tags [[code-efficiency]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/code-efficiency/info), and [[performance]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/performance/info) or [[optimization]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/optimization/info) is supposed to be. I think [code-efficiency] should be merged into one of the others. I think the better merge target is [performance], as its excerpt explicitly says: "For questions pertaining to the measurement or improvement of code efficiency", and it already has [efficiency] as one of its synonyms.

Number of questions with each tag:

- performance: [39,968](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance)
- optimization: [13,295](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optimization)
- code-efficiency: [423](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-efficiency)
- code-efficiency and performance: [137](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-efficiency+performance)
- code-efficiency and optimization: [13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-efficiency+optimization)
- code-efficiency and performance and optimization: [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-efficiency+performance+optimization)

Comment: For me personally, “code efficiency” means something completely different than “performance”. I can write efficient code that performs terrible, and I can create high-performance code that is just not efficient in code at all. It seems that rather the tag wikis should be updated.

Comment: @poke "I can write efficient code that performs terrible" I really don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: I think poke uses "efficient code" to mean "succinct code" — a high ratio of work-performed to text-written. I share the viewpoint expressed by poke.

Comment: Yeah, for me code is efficient when it’s easy to read/understand, easy and fast to write (not necessarily short). None of that will have any necessary impact on performance though, and the reverse isn’t true either. So I don’t really agree that the terms match.

Comment: @poke Ohh okay. I would use [readability](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/readability/info) or [code-readability](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/code-readability/info) for that (which are also deserving of merging into each other). What Cerran is saying is more like "code-brevity", for which there does not seem to be a tag, except *maybe* [simplify](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/simplify/info). Neither of these seem to be the common interpretations for "code-efficiency" though, judging by the questions currently using that tag.

Answer (score 5):

Agreed. Disambiguation or merging via synonyms is needed here. Not only does the  [performance] excerpt mention "code efficiency", but its [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/performance/info) also says, "If your question pertains to optimization... consider using this tag."

The difference is not at all clear from the names. I initially thought [code-efficiency] might be about making code very succinct, but its tag wiki describes it as something more similar to [performance] or [optimization].

As far as I can tell, they should all be synonyms.

Comment: *“I initially thought […] but its tag wiki describes it […]”* – Then shouldn’t we instead fix the tag wiki to reflect what one would actually expect from “code efficiency”?

Comment: @poke Yes, but only if the majority agrees. I don't know whether my interpretation is the most common one or not.

Comment: Well, judging from just the tag names, I would certainly agree with the interpretation. And I would believe that tags should be clear from just their name, without having to read their wiki.

Comment: @poke: I don't think that changing the description would change anything. Under `code-efficiency` many understand simply `efficiency` and they don't look at the description before posting. We may describe `code-efficiency` as `code-readability` or `code-succinctness`, but it's futile because of word `efficiency` inside.

Comment: code efficiency to me is different from performance.  The reason being that code could be written, read, and even run efficiently, but at the same time, it might have memory leaks that degrades performance.  When I think of performance, I think of how a system as whole runs a program.  Also, I think performance is more subjective.  2 different programs may run faster than the other on different machines depending on the machines' configuration.  A good example of this is games.  1 game runs faster on PS3, while another game runs faster on Xbox360.

Comment: @cluemein Just curious, what exactly do you define as "efficient" code? In my head, "efficient" code is code that makes the best use of available resources; thus, code with memory leaks cannot be called efficient because it's not making the best use of memory.

Comment: @user3580294 You have a point there, but only partly.  Mainly, I find code to be efficient when it uses the smallest amount of memory and instructions possible to achieve a task, and it's algorithms have a small runtime (n being better than n^2).  That doesn't necessarily mean that it won't have memory leaks though.  Especially if using a programming language that doesn't have automatic garbage-collection.  Memory leaks lead to poor performance, but doesn't mean the code itself isn't efficient.

Comment: @cluemein Doesn't having a memory leak mean that you aren't using the smallest amount of memory possible, by definition? It's like if you have a program that eats up 50% of CPU time idle-spinning, and still saying it's efficient. Your definition of efficiency besides memory leaks makes sense though.

Comment: @user3580294 There can be different kinds of memory leaks.  An example would be older versions of IE (maybe current versions too, don't know, since I haven't used IE in a long time), where it would fail to deallocate memory that had been used when it got exited.  Basically, it could use very little memory, but if that memory was not de-allocated when the program was over, your computer would find itself slowly losing available memory.  That was a major problem for IE if I remember correctly.

Comment: @cluemein Different kinds of memory leak? And in any case, how is that functionally different from a program actually holding onto the leaked memory? A program isn't efficient if it manages resources badly.

Comment: @user3580294 Here is an example to explain what I am trying to say.  Lets say you wrote two programs that use the same algorithm and do the same thing.  One is written in Java (and doesn't use Just-in-time compiling), the other is written in C++.  There is no algorithm included for garbage collection.  If the program is large and complex, C++ may perform the program tasks faster than the Java program due to it having direct memory access (hence more efficient).  However, Java has its own garbage collection, so it will not have as much of a memory leak problem.

Comment: continued:  If the computer is restarted routinely, the C++ will typically be faster.  However, if the program is run multiple times without restarting the computer, the computer that runs the C++ version will slow down.  This will not happen to the Java program.  Another way of looking at it:  the C++ program has no garbage collection, but the Java does, adding a drop of runtime complexity to the Java algorithm runtime.  The C++ might have a runtime complexity of n, while the Java one might have a runtime complexity of n*log(n) or 2n.  A lower runtime complexity= more efficient.

Comment: Another example, is the fact that certain graphics and game engines are coded in such a way that they run better on different graphics cards.  Some game engines will do better on a NVIDIA card, while others will do better on an AMD/ATI card.  This is due to the different technologies being used in them.  Thus performance in this case has nothing to do with efficiency, but is connected to the format-hardware combination.

Comment: @cluemein Now, you aren't really making a fair comparison there; you're comparing a program with a memory leak with a program that doesn't have a memory leak. The C++ program doesn't manage its resources well, while the Java program does. The C++ program is more performant (runs faster), but less efficient (doesn't manage resources well). You won't *notice* the lack of efficiency for a single run, but it'll come back to bite you if you need to run the program many times.

Comment: I don't think you can talk about runtime complexity like that, because you're essentially comparing apples and oranges. The complexity of a GC algorithm depends on different factors than the complexity of whatever other algorithm/data structures the Java program is using, so you can't mash them into the same metric. The fact that GC is nondeterministic just makes things worse. Maybe the GC never runs, maybe it runs constantly, which makes the runtime complexity of the overall program *really* hard to figure out.

Comment: In any case, you shouldn't be including GC into a complexity calculation. Complexity should be calculated for a particular algorithm/implementation, and it's extremely rare for GC to be included *directly* in that algorithm/implementation. You never see analysis of data structures/sorting algorithms/etc. including GC factors... Because the GC is a totally different factor. If both programs are written the same way, they will have the same complexity, by definition.

Comment: And depending on how one wishes to argue it, you can be incorrect for the graphics card comparison. The performance depends on the efficiency of the particular software-hardware combination; if you're 100% efficient on both an AMD and NVidia card, then the performance differences come down to one card being more/less efficient at a particular kind of calculation than the other. So you can argue that efficiency still defines performance in that case.

Comment: Because I can't move to chat for some reason, use [this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/57515/temp-chat)