# Synonym suggestion: [performance] and [optimization]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

I've come across many posts that have either or both of the tags [[performance]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/performance/info) and [[optimization]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/optimization/info). Maybe there is some nuanced difference between these concepts that I am missing, but it seems to me that they are interchangeable. The description of [performance] explicitly says:

> **If your question pertains to optimization**, whether it be database queries, algorithms, reducing network/transactional overhead, or anything that deals with speed or capacity, **consider using this tag**.

There also is [this thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250970/merge-code-efficiency-into-performance) from a couple of years ago that highlights the similarity between [performance] and [optimization], but the thread was focused on merging [code-efficiency] into either [performance] or [optimization]. Ultimately, [code-efficiency] was merged into [performance].

What do people think? Does it make sense to combine these, or am I missing something? Which one would it make more sense to merge into the other? 
I might lean toward [performance] just because it is more popular, with 61,602 tags compared to 20,171 for [optimization].

Comment: I don't understand why these need to be synonyms as their tag wikis describe different worlds. I wouldn't consider those words to be synonym nor the tags.

Comment: Performance can include optimization, but I think it encompasses much more. For instance, you might increase performance by adding more RAM to your server. That's not optimization. Of course, that also doesn't belong on SO, but I digress :).

Comment: Over a year later, I find myself wondering the same thing. To me it's not clear when one or the other should be used, and the tag usage guidance is still not very helpful for either one of them.