# Clean-up [coding-efficiency]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, clean-up

I recently came across the [coding-efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-efficiency) tag. Its excerpt is highly meta and opinion based:

> For questions regarding programmer efficiency, not computer efficiency, e.g. tightening one's edit-compile-test loop.

Another thing clear from this excerpt is that it is not to be used as a tag relating to computation time. [The latest question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49029203/5211833) with the tag is already an example of the tag being used for computation time issues.

Questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48796787/5211833) ('How to write this piece of code more efficiently') do adhere more to the excerpt, but run the risk of turning into a code-golf like efficiency: sacrifice everything for the number of bytes. At best the tag is just ambiguous here: what do you want to make more efficient?

All in all a lot of the 118 questions currently tagged [coding-efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-efficiency) should have the tag removed, as they are about computational efficiency, and the excerpt and wiki could use a rewrite to make them less meta and opinion based.

Will you help in cleaning up this tag?

I just stumbled on [this merge request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250970/5211833) related to [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance) and several others, this seems a good course of action to me, as [code-efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-efficiency) is already a synonym of [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance). So clean up the tag first, then make it a synonym of [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance).

Comment: Why do we have this tag again?  "Coding this more efficiently" is something that is wildly up to debate and subjective, since...well, to start, we don't know enough about their data set to say that the code is truly optimal for their inputs.

Comment: Basically this sounds like all questions tagged with this tag should move to codereview...

Comment: what about tools (like IDEs, plugins) that help coding more efficiently ? Reading the tag names, it seems to me that "coding-efficiency" should be about improving efficiency of a developper, not the performance of the actual code produced.

Comment: (Make [coding-efficiency] more efficient)

Comment: @Pac0 that is indeed the case, but, as stated in the question, that's off-topic for Stack Overflow, as what might be efficient for one developer, is not necessarily efficient for another. I, for one, code very efficient when in my tiger-print pyjamas sipping whisky. It would be a better fit for [softwareengineering.SE] I think.

Comment: @Adriaan If the tag is off-topic in your opinion, why clean it up and not burninate it? It only has 115 questions, and we already have [tag:performance] and [tag:optimization]. I don't see the use of this tag, even after cleaning up and rewriting the excerpt.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth see the last paragraph; clean up the tag to not be about *coding*-efficiency, but *code*-efficiency and then merge with [tag:performance] would be my preferred course of action.

Comment: Sounds like burnination with a twist to me. Take all the rightly tagged questions, untag them, and then merge with a tag for the wrongly tagged questions, that seems like an odd thing to do to me.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth the problem is that the tag is currently used for A) the thing the excerpt states, and B) for performance issues. A) is off-topic and those questions (and thus the tag) should not be here. That leaves all the questions in B), which mostly have the same misuse of the tag, which is easily solved by synonymising. This has the added benefit of the tag not resurfacing again to be the OT thing it is now.

Answer (score 2):

As of 1st December 2021, this tag now has 348 questions, and it's still the case that the vast majority of them are about [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance), not "programmer efficiency".

It seems to me that if the tag should be kept, it should be renamed to [programmer-productivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programmer-productivity) to avoid it being an attractive nuisance to people who ignore the tag info. However, in my opinion the tag should just be burninated; questions about programmer productivity are unlikely to be on-topic on Stack Overflow, and are likely to be opinion-based.

It's possible that a question about programmer productivity could have a definite answer based on facts and fact-based sources (e.g. academic research), but those questions really belong on [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) anyway: questions about *"software development methods and practices"* are explicitly on-topic there.